# add user profiles fields into comment fields

Tags: 7, entities, users, comments

I'd like when a user comments, to display his information.

Let's assume I do have in my user profile 2 fields, Job title and Biography.

When a user comments, I would like to get those 2 fields and display them as comment fields.(same for existing comments)
It will then display the comment + job title + bio

What the best solution for that ?

I was thinking about a preprocess to load the $user but maybe there is some configuration which could do it instead.
In this example I added 2 fields in the comment section of my content type then I'm trying to get the user profile infos to the current fields.

```
function template_preprocess_comment(&$vars) {
      if($vars['comment']->uid !== 0){
        $user = user_load($vars['comment']->uid);
        $vars['field_job_title'] = $user->field_job_title;
        $vars['field_bio'] = $user->field_bio;
      }
}
```

Final approach was:
For the existing one that what I came out with:

```
function hook_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category){
    //get all node we need
    $results = db_select('node', 'n')
                  ->fields('n', array('nid'))
                  ->condition('type', 'my_content_type', 'LIKE')
                  ->execute();

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $nids[] = $result->nid;
    }
    foreach ($nids as $key => $nid) {
        //get all comment ids
        $result = db_select('comment')
            ->fields('comment', array('cid'))
            ->condition('nid', $nid, '=')
            ->condition('uid', $account->uid, '=')
            ->execute();

        $cids = $result->fetchCol();
        $comments=comment_load_multiple($cids);
        foreach($comments as $comment) {
            //load comment
            // $user = user_load($comment->uid);
            if(isset($edit['field_job_title']) && isset($edit['field_bio']) && $account->uid !== 0){
                //change data of the comment
                $comment->field_job_title = $edit['field_job_title'];
                $comment->field_bio = $edit['field_bio'];
                //save it
                comment_save($comment);
            }
        }
    }
}

function hook_comment_presave($comment) {
    //if not user, otherwise it does it when you do the comment_save($comment) from the user_presave, then it won't work
    if(arg(0) !== 'user'){
        $user = user_load($comment->uid);
        if($user->uid != 0){
            $comment->field_job_title = isset($user->field_job_title) ? $user->field_job_title : NULL;
            $comment->field_bio = isset($user->field_bio) ? $user->field_bio : NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

and this one to hide the current fields when you comment:

```
function template_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['field_bio']['#access'] = FALSE;
    $form['field_job_title']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to display the info on the comment form or the comment it self?

Comment: on the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
function hook_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category){
    //get all node we need
    $results = db_select('node', 'n')
                  ->fields('n', array('nid'))
                  ->condition('type', 'my_content_type', 'LIKE')
                  ->execute();

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $nids[] = $result->nid;
    }
    foreach ($nids as $key => $nid) {
        //get all comment ids
        $result = db_select('comment')
            ->fields('comment', array('cid'))
            ->condition('nid', $nid, '=')
            ->condition('uid', $account->uid, '=')
            ->execute();

        $cids = $result->fetchCol();
        $comments=comment_load_multiple($cids);
        foreach($comments as $comment) {
            //load comment
            // $user = user_load($comment->uid);
            if(isset($edit['field_job_title']) && isset($edit['field_bio']) && $account->uid !== 0){
                //change data of the comment
                $comment->field_job_title = $edit['field_job_title'];
                $comment->field_bio = $edit['field_bio'];
                //save it
                comment_save($comment);
            }
        }
    }
}

function hook_comment_presave($comment) {
    //if not user, otherwise it does it when you do the comment_save($comment) from the user_presave, then it won't work
    if(arg(0) !== 'user'){
        $user = user_load($comment->uid);
        if($user->uid != 0){
            $comment->field_job_title = isset($user->field_job_title) ? $user->field_job_title : NULL;
            $comment->field_bio = isset($user->field_bio) ? $user->field_bio : NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

and this one to hide the current fields when you comment:

```
function template_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['field_bio']['#access'] = FALSE;
    $form['field_job_title']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is ok. But you could also

- Add a field on the comment fields of your content type that uses a reference to the user
- On hook_comment_presave fill out the user reference field with the uid of the logged in user
- On manage display of your comment fields, just render the user field as a rendered entity
- You could use a custom view mode on user that only shows the fields "job title" and "bio".

Comment: My solution didn't work actually, nothing changed. I'll try the one with the rendered entity

Comment: Let me know if it does the job :)

Comment: I used field reference but it just didn't want to display the reference...

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of your hook_comment_insert?

Comment: I'm sorry you have to use hook_comment_presave to fill out the user reference: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_presave/7

Comment: The problem is with presave it'll do it only when someone comments and not for the existing one!

Comment: For the existing ones you will have to write a bulk edit function. You can use this query db_query('SELECT * FROM {comments} WHERE nid = %d', $nid); and then set the uid and save the comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/1030676

Comment: that exactly what I came out with :) thank you Robin, now I'll try the presave for the new comments which will be added.

Comment: If this approach works, can you upvote the question. That way users know that the answer is legit ;)